# Psql restore dump file

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to restore my dump file.

I am working on a virtual machine with windows. When I try to import the file into my new database I get the following error:

> no such file or directory.

I tried with different ways to fix the problem, but I still can not import my dump file. I hope somebody can give me some advice how can I fix it.

When I try to import I used the `\i` meta command and the file path.
examples:

```
NewDB# \i 'c:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/scripts/file.sql'
```

I read some advices and some of them mentioned move the file to different directories, I tried also this, but I still have the problem.

Comment: Try double quotes: `\i "c:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/scripts/file.sql"` (unrelated, but: it is a **really** bad idea to store user data under `c:\Program Files` that directory is write protected for a good reason)

Comment: Hi a_horse_with_no_name, I stored my file directly over c: now, if I use double quotes I got Invalid argument, and using single quotes still I get no such file or directory. newdb# \i 'c:/file.sql'

Answer (score 0):

pythonanywhere bash restore postgresql from dump:

1. find out name of database and name of user:
   postgres=# \c

psql (12.7 (Ubuntu 12.7-1.pgdg20.04+1), server 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-2.pgdg16.04+1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "super".

2. get address and port on Databases Postgres tab e.g.:
   magula10-2617.postgres.pythonanywhere-services.com

12617

3. restore database named "postgres" (user "super") from dump (will prompt for postgresql password):
   $ psql -h magula10-2617.postgres.pythonanywhere-services.com -p 12617 -U super -W postgres < 2022_4_4_localhost_dump